# stored procedure always returning -1 in entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, entity

In my sql I have one stored procedure which is querying data from other server using linked server.

Bellow is my stored procedure

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE [FIMS].[GetContactInfo]
   @ContactID nvarchar(MAX)
   AS
   BEGIN
   DECLARE @LinkServerName VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @UserName VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @Password VARCHAR(25)

SET @LinkServerName = 'myserverip'
SET @UserName = 'username'
SET @Password = 'password'

IF ((@LinkServerName IS NOT NULL) AND (@UserName IS NOT NULL) AND (@Password IS NOT NULL))
BEGIN 

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM master.dbo.sysservers WHERE srvname = @LinkServerName)
    BEGIN
        exec sp_addlinkedserver @server=@LinkServerName;
        exec sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname= @LinkServerName,@useself=false, @rmtuser=@UserName, @rmtpassword=@Password;
    END

    DECLARE
    @strSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @strSQL = 'SELECT 
                fcContact.Name as CompanyName, fcPhone.Area + fcPhone.Prefix + fcPhone.Trunk as ContactNumber
                FROM 
                '+ '[' + @LinkServerName + ']' + '.[MyDB].[AssContactPhone] fcAssContactPhone INNER JOIN
                '+ '[' + @LinkServerName + ']' + '.[MyDB].[Contact] fcContact ON fcAssContactPhone.ContactID = fcContact.ContactID INNER JOIN
                '+ '[' + @LinkServerName + ']' + '.[MyDB].[Phone] fcPhone ON fcAssContactPhone.PhoneID = fcPhone.PhoneID
                where fcContact.ContactID = '+ @ContactID +''
EXEC(@strSQL)   
END
END
```

I am using that stored procedure in my Entity Framework, But it always returns result as '-1'

How can I use result returned by this stored procedure in my entity framework ?

Comment: you are assigning static 'myserverip to the linked server name paramter. is it correct? if yes what is the need of NULL check

Comment: @bmsqldev that I have done just for showing stored procedure here. Taht is not a problem here.

Comment: ok. while fetching data from linked server. you should follow below format  [linked server name].[database name].[schema name]. [table name] . i think you missed either schema name/ database name in your dynamic query

Comment: Could you change your WHERE clause as `WHERE fcContact.ContactID = ''' + @ContactID + '''';` and try

Comment: `PRINT @strSQL` and execute the return query in SSMS, you can get a clue.

Answer (score 0):

I have to assume it's being called using a C# command, as the question is tagged as such, in which case, you'll probably find that it's not the SP that's returning -1 but the method itself. Without seeing the code, it's difficult to say exactly why but this often occurs because of the way the SQL command is called. The -1 can simply be a response to say that the SQL command was executed correctly. You need to use the reader command rather than execute, if you want to return the result, in C#.